# Issue with simple MySQL Script

Tags: mysql, access-violation

Why is the SQL below Producing the indicated error?

```
SET @natureRegTime:=7200;
SET @natureTime:=1;
```

Error it produces is

```
QueryException
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14
10.25.0
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @natureTime:=1'
```

I've tried without the colon and get the same result. It doesn't matter what the second line is it throws the same error. I tested it directly in MySQL but do not get the error.

I also tried removing all the comments just leaving the two SET commands but I get the same result.

Any suggestions as to what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the variables at the beginning of the script

```
DECLARE @natureRegTime AS INT, @natureTime AS INT
SET @natureRegTime= 7200
SET @natureTime = 1
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Throws an error about Declare since it's not inside a procedure.

Comment: if it's not a procedure where are you running this commands? can you provide the complete query please?

Comment: Finally, figured it out. I'm using Laravel with DB Query and used DB::statement($query) instead of DB::unprepared($query). Script is now working as expected.

Comment: I'm reading an SQL Script, modifying it and the running it. The script is a raw SQL file.

Comment: @Alejandro23 You do not need to declare user-defines variables (`@var`). The `DECLARE @var` is used in SQL Server and in Sybase, not in MySQL.